# Android searching for a bitmap's prominent color

Tags: android, colors

I get a bitmap drawn by the user and try to extract the prominent color from it by doing what you can see below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
                final Map<Integer, Integer> getColorsFromImage;
                {
                    int mostlyUsed = 0;
                    final int widthInPx = drawView.getDrawingCache().getWidth();
                    final int heightInPx = drawView.getDrawingCache().getHeight();
                    Map<Integer, Integer> colors = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // rgb

                    int count = 0;
                    int currentColor = 0;
                    for(int x = 0; x < widthInPx; x++){
                        for(int y = 0; y < heightInPx; y++){

                            count = 0;
                            currentColor = drawView.getDrawingCache().getPixel(widthInPx, heightInPx);
                            if(colors.containsKey(currentColor)){
                                count = colors.get(currentColor) + 1;
                            }
                            if (count > mostlyUsed) {
                            mostlyUsed = count;
                            }
                            colors.put(currentColor, count);
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    Integer mostlyUsedColor = colors.get(mostlyUsed);  

                    switch (mostlyUsedColor){
                        case #A52A2A:
                      do sth;
                       break;
                         case #FFFFFF:
                       (...)
                    }
```

Do you have any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newest support v7 library, there is a class for dong just what you need. From the documentation:

> The v7 palette support library includes the Palette class, which lets you extract prominent colors from an image

[You can read more about it here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)

Simple usage:

```
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        // colors generated
    }
});
```